# Number of pairs of edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles in complete graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, hamiltonian-graphs

**Question:**
how many *pairs* $\lbrace H_i, H_j\rbrace$ of edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles are in the complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ vertices?

while I could find information to the maximal number of edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles in $K_n$ I was not able to find anything about the number of combinations $\lbrace H_1,\,\dots,\,H_h\rbrace$, i.e. the number of ways to select $h$ edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles from $K_n$, specifically for $h=2$

Comment: It should be relatively straightforward to write an inclusion-exclusion expression for this number.

Comment: Related to [A002816](http://oeis.org/A002816), isn't it? Number of Hamiltonian cycles in the complement of the cycle graph $C_n$?

Comment: Let $\ n>2\ $ be a prime number. Let the vertices form a regular n-gon. There are $\ a:=\frac{n-1}2\ $ Hamiltonian cycles, one for each length of the edges. Then there are $\ \binom a2\ $ (unordered) pairs of these cycles where the members of the same pair are edge-disjoint.